# dutch national flag sort in single traverse

Tags: java, dutch-national-flag-problem

Given an array A of size N containing 0s, 1s, and 2s; you need to sort the array in ascending order.

**Input:**
The first line contains an integer 'T' denoting the total number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test cases contains two lines of input. The first line denotes the size of the array N. The second lines contains the elements of the array A separated by spaces.

below is the java code
Why the highest element does not go at the rear end of the array?

```java
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //code
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T =sc.nextInt();
        while(T>0)
        {
            int N= sc.nextInt();
            byte A[]=new byte[N];

            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                A[i]=sc.nextByte();
            }

            GFG g= new GFG();
            g.sortarray(A,N);

            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            T--;
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    public static void sortarray(byte[] A,int n)
    {
       int low=0;
       int mid=0;
       int high=A.length-1;
       byte temp=0;

       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           if(A[i]==0){
               temp=A[low];
               A[low]=A[i];
               A[i]=temp;
               low++;
               mid++;
           }
           if(A[i]==2){ 
                temp=A[high];
                A[high]=A[i];
                A[i]=temp; 
                high--;
           }
           else{
            ++mid;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**For Input:**

```
2
5
0 2 1 2 0
3
0 1 0
```

**Your Output is:**

```
0 0 2 2 1 
0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your code step by step in IDE or trace your code on whiteboard. You have an error with algorithm